# VueJs not detected in Laravel using Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, laravel-5.7

I am trying to setup VueJs using laravel 5.7 and mix and it just says VueJs not detected. I have run `npm install`. Here is my welcome view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css">

        <style type="text/css">body { padding-top: 40px; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root" class="container">
            <message title="Hello World" body="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."></message>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my app js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('message', require('./components/Message.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#root'
});
```

I can't figure out why VueJs won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have any script tag in your view..

Comment: ah ok thank you! the simplest things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said, you missed the script tag.

If you are compiling your sources you should use `mix()` rather than `asset()`, as it will respect things such as [file versioning](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) with `mix.version()`.

e.g.

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Combining both is a better practice.   mix() won't append the app url.

Comment: mix() does return a relative path, which is fine in most cases. If you really need the domain prepended, you can use `asset(mix(...))` or `secure_asset(mix(...))` as @Devon said.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add this script in your index.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks , this make the magic

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

in laravel I place it inside the blade HTML and then reload the page , F12 and there was the vue tab working and now I can see the tags of vue.